# Strange code in assigning an uint

Tags: c#

I was wondering isn't `uint` supposed to be an integer?

So can someone explain me this code because it doesn't look like a number:

```
const uint INIT_D = 0x10325476;
```

Comment: It is hexadecimal notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: Include the code in the body of the question. Also, what specifically are you confused about? The `0x` prefix? It means hexadecimal. A quick Google search will save everyone time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [C# language specification (2.4.4.2 Integer literals)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) `0x` in an integer assignment is the prefix for an [hexadecimal notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

So this:

```
const uint INIT_D = 0x10325476;
```

yields the same result as:

```
const uint INIT_D = 271733878U;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong, downvotes can be random. uint literals end in U e.g. 271733878U but you answered the question.

Comment: @buffjape That might be my flaw, indeed. Thanks for pointing it out!